# How do I fix "Expression expected. ts(1109)" in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I encountered VSCode error "Expression expected. ts(1009)" while opening one of the reactjs file. `do` and `if` were highlighted red. 
But I can run the code in my local development environment and also no problem compiling. I guess this is due to VSCode Editor bug.

Other editor like Atom or Sublime Text are fine. I used ternary operation in React to solve it but things get really complicated if there are too many `else if`.

```
<div className='form'>
    // Form stuffs
</div>
{
    do{
      if (hasBreakfast) {
        <span>Breakfast Included</span>
      } else if {
        <span>Breakfast Not Included</span>
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any methods to solve the warning in VSCode?

Comment: You need to put that code inside a function. then call it in the render method

Comment: and your code doesn't make any sense

Comment: This isn't valid JSX syntax. I don't know why you have `do` at the start of it, and you can't embed if/else statements inside it. Try this instead: `<div>{hasBreakfast && <span>Breakfast Included</span>}</div>`

Comment: This is from someone else code. VSCode throws error when I opend it. @Jayce444 has good point. Ternary operator can be used to solve this warning. But it will get complicated if there are many `else if`. Things gonna get nested in ternary

Comment: Well if you have complex logic then do NOT embed it inside your component, because you're right it will get messy and hard to read. Instead, pull the logic out into a function then just call the function in your JSX, e.g.: `<div>{includedMeals()}</div>`

Comment: @Jayce444 Hi, sorry I encounter a similar problem. I'm wondering if there is some kind of rules that reactJS follow, can you give me the keyword so I can search for more example or references? Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `if` statement needs an expression to assert if that block of code should be used.

ex:

```js
if (a === true) {
  // do something
} else if (b === true) {
  // do something else
}
```

If you just want to render the `Breakfast Not Included` you can just use `else` without the `if`. Or do make it simpler you could make a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
{
  hasBreakfast ? <span>Breakfast Included</span> : <span>Breakfast Not Included</span>;
}
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect Cory. `a = true` is an assignment, not a statement.

Comment: Wow silly me haha. Thanks for the obvious syntax issue @PixelPlex I was just at the beginning of my JS career 4 years ago haha.

Answer (score 0):

In My case I am getting this `Expression expected.ts(1109)` error using ternary condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
  <Fragment>
  // JSX to render goes here...
  </Fragment>
);
```

I received the same error on the last line. 
I added the fragment element to force the return () to receive one parent element. You can also accomplish this by wrapping your return code is a 'div' element. The issue there however, is you will have random empty 'div' s.

The docs explain it better than I can. https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

`do` expressions, as used in the original question, are actually "valid" JSX/JS syntax [if you're using the babel syntax/plugin that supports the `do` expression proposal](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-do-expressions). The reason VS Code is displeased is because [TypeScript itself does not support the syntax](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18535#issuecomment-388518636). If it's working in your development environment anyway, [again that's probably Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-do-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

**Import Cost VSCode Extension** it's encountered this error for me, just uninstalled fixed my issue.